# DOS 01h Read character behavior on EOF

Tags: x86, nasm, x86-16, dos, x86-emulation

Using 01h interrupt ([AH = 01h - READ CHARACTER FROM STANDARD INPUT, WITH ECHO](http://spike.scu.edu.au/%7Ebarry/interrupts.html#ah01)), what will be output at the end of stdin for a cat program? Is ^Z (1Ah) used to mark the end of stdin by convention?

Testing [this program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62230/simple-cat-program/170458#170458) with emu2 (`emu2 doscat.com < input.txt`) results in FFh being constantly printed, although that might be from emu2 being a C program and reading EOFs as -1.

```
section .text
start:
        mov ah, 01h ; read char from stdin with echo
        int 21h     ; call DOS services
        jmp start
```

Comment: With int 21h/ah=1 ^Z is not interpreted, thus not causing an EOF if input is redirected. So it will keep reading characters from STDIN until you break with control-C.

Comment: If reading from a redirected source you would have to modify the code to search for 0ffh and stop reading once found. Note if there is a 0ffh in the input stream as part of the file that will also stop. You might want to consider using Int 21h/ah=3fh to read from standard input. You can check the return value for 0 bytes read which would be EOF. See: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2783.htm (note: file handle 0 is standard input in dos)